# Is it correct to state, that bounded function, bounded in domain?

Tags: functions, upper-lower-bounds

I started read some further mathematics book, and continuously suspect that it is pretty low-level and contains mistakes.

In the current section I read, as the book states, that: "function $y = f(x)$ is called *bounded above* **in the function's domain $X$**, if there exists positive number $m$, so in inequality $f(x) \le  m,\space ∀x ∈ X$ is true".

Is it correct to state, that it bounded (limited) in the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (i.e. on X), but not on the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function) (i.e. on Y)?

Why is domain (i.e. X) related at all, if the only thing that is "restricted" is function value, i.e. range (i.e. Y)?

Every other source I found, formulates, that such function is bounded in its range, not domain.

Or is it not important, and I'm being picky?

---

According to Wikipedia, (originally Jeffrey, Alan. Mathematics for Engineers and Scientists, 5th Edition):

> A function $f$ defined on some set $X$ with real or complex values is
> called bounded if the set of its values is bounded. In other words,
> there exists a real number $M$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$ **for all x in
> X**

So, function bound is not related, does not depend anyhow on function's domain ($X$). I think it could been confused with [local maximum and minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_and_minimum#Definition).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Why bounded over $X$, if, what is restricted is $Y$? For example, in case of $sin(x)$, the $x$ is not restricted, it can be any of $R$, but $y$ is restricted from -1 to 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Short answer

No, it is not correct to state, that bounded function, bounded on domain.

#### Prove

Function, or generally a map, can be defined in few ways:

- Analytically: using algebraical expression and specifying [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (x) and [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function) (y) set, for example: $Y:y=f(x),$ for $x∈X⊆\mathbb{R}, y∈Y⊆X$;
- By explicitly determining domain and range, for example: $f: X\rightarrow Y$, $X = \{1,2,3\}, Y=\{3,2,1\}$
- By plot

One common aspect of all ways is that domain and range sets define the function.

By changing domain set, we are redefying a function, we considering another function, either, if we considering a part of domain, that is subdomain, then we can't use bounding term, because by definition, function must be considered for all x [1].

If to consider only some x's, i.e. only part of domain, i.e. some subdomain, then we are dealing with [local maximum and minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_and_minimum#Definition) [2].

#### Summary

Function is not bounding on domain, because the value that is restricted belongs to range and not to domain; by changing domain of the function, same function bounding is not changed, because function with another domain is another function, since function is defined by its domain.

**Bounding function is bounding on its range (Y), and not on the domain (X).**

#### Links

[1] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function

[2] - https://math.dartmouth.edu/opencalc2/cole/lecture10.pdf (page 2)

Answer (score 1):

It is very important which domain you consider. Take for example the function $f(x) = x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If we restrict $f$ to, let's say, $[-1,1]$, then it's bounded from above by $1$, since $f(x) = x \leq 1$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. If we consider the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$ instead, then $f$ is clearly not bounded as $f(x) = x \rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. Hope this clarifies your problem.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148505/discussion-on-answer-by-stange-is-it-correct-to-state-that-bounded-function-bo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.